# Laravel Elixir use Typescript instead of Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, typescript, gulp, laravel-elixir

I have a project that uses laravel 5.2 here I use laravel elixir for javascript pre-processors and I find that the typescript is easier to use because it is object-oriented and can also be compiled into Javascript, the question is can I combine Javascript and typescript using laravel Elixir? is there a library that can do that?

```
mix.script(['jquery.js', 'app.ts'], 'all.js']);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it doesn't support TypeScript out of the box : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#babel recommend just running `tsc -w -p ./example/tsconfig.json` and using the `.js` output as it is in `mix.script`.

You can even use `concurrently` to run both `tsc -w` with other tasks : https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently